# Knockout not updating UI after ViewModel is updated

Tags: knockout.js

I have a ViewModel bound to my UI

```
<div class="editor-label-medium-bold">
    <div data-bind="text: 'Cancellation Amount'"></div>
</div>
<div class="editor-field-short">
    <div id="CancellationAmount" data-bind="text: CancellationAmount"></div>
</div>
```

The value for CancellationAmount does get displayed on when ko.applyBindings(xxx) is called. All good up to this point.

I have a JQueryUI datepicker, and upon date change I get an updated figure for the cancellation amount. This gets the right value back.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    method: "GET",
    url: '@Url.Action(MVC.XYZ.ActionNames.GetCancellationAmount, MVC.XYZ.Name)',
    data: { date: mdl.CancelDate(), policyid: '@ViewBag.PolicyID' }
})
.done(function (response) {
    mdl.CancellationAmount = ko.observable(response);
    $('#CancellationAmount').val(response);
})
.fail(function (response) {
    alert('fail');
});
```

Neither of the two lines in the "done" callback are updating the UI. I test this with Chrome and in the console, mdl.CancellationAmount() returns the correct figure, yet the UI wont budge.

I am on the verge of unbinding this field and manually update it with JQuery like I attempt on the second line of the "done" callback. I think because the field is bound, knockout stops JQuery (maybe anything else...) from updating it.

I should probably mention this line of code:

```
mdl.CancellationAmount = ko.observable(mdl.AnnualPremium());
```

On initial load, my model from the server sends null for CancellationAmount, so I copy another value to it which is a positive decimal figure, but I unwrap that, so dont think that is the issue. This line is just before ko.applyBindings(xxx)

Has anyone seen this before, or has any idea how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You assign data to `mdl.CancellationAmount` in a wrong way. It is already observable so you should use () to assign value in `done` function. Rewrite your callback as follow:

```
.done(function (response) {
    mdl.CancellationAmount(response);
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much Artem, that was the last piece of the puzzle!